# How to replace "^" with space?

Tags: shell, text-processing

How can `^` be replaced with space  in Unix?

Input:

```
ab^cd^ef
```

Output:

```
ab cd ef
```

I have tried `sub(/^/, " & ", str)` but output is same as input.

Comment: In bash: `echo "${str//^/ }"`...

Comment: Your problem is that ^ is a special character for regexps.

Comment: You say `sub(/^/, " & ", str)` but what language is that? (It looks vaguely Perl-ish to me, but without context, it's really hard to tell.) Best is if you can provide a ready-made script (including a `#!`) that people can directly execute which demonstrates exactly the problem you are having and nothing more.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, that's `awk`.

Answer (score 17):

That's the job for `tr`:

```
$ str=ab^cd^ef
$ printf '%s\n' "$str" | tr '^' ' '
ab cd ef
```

---

In `bash`, `ksh93`, `mksh`, `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${str//^/ }"
```

In `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- "${str:gs/^/ /}"
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `sed`,

```
$ echo "ab^cd^ef" | sed 's,\^, ,g'
ab cd ef
```

Already [commented by @jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306315/how-to-replace-with-space#comment538385_306315) you can use inline shell string replacement,

```
$ str="ab^cd^ef"
$ echo "${str//^/ }"
ab cd ef
```

Another one, suggested by [@someonewithpc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306315/how-to-replace-with-space/306322#comment538750_306322)

```
$ echo "ab^cd^ef" | sed 'y,^, ,'
ab cd ef
```

(Note : `y` is used for transforming characters.)

Comment: I'd prefer to use 'y/^/ /'

Comment: @someonewithpc thanks, incorporated your suggestion in my answer. If you would like, post it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to do the substitution in `awk` as your

> ```
> sub(/^/, " & ", str)
> ```

suggests, you'd need to escape the `^` as that's an extended regular expression operator (`/^/` means match at the beginning of the string):

```
sub(/\^/, " & ", str)
```

would replace the first occurrence of `^` within `str` with `^` (space-`^`-space). Use `sub(/\^/, " ", str)` to replace with space, and `gsub(/\^/, " ", str)` to replace every occurrence.

Note that you can't use <strike>`sub(/[^]/, " & ", str)`</strike> as `^` happens to also be special inside `[...]`. Most `awk` implementations support `sub(/[\^]/, " & ", str)` though.

Comment: How about set FS to ^ and OFS to space